# Java can't read XML file

Tags: java, xml

I need to read a XML file returned from a web service.

I was following this [tutorial](http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Java-Read-XML-File-Guide-td2957086.html), and I have a error in this line:

`Element firstPersonElement = (Element)firstPersonNode;`

The error:

`inconvertible types
  required: javax.swing.text.html.parser.Element
  found:    org.w3c.dom.Node`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

My imports

```
import br.com.portaldeideias.model.ErroXML;
import br.com.portaldeideias.model.TributosNFe;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.List;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.Element;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
```

Comment: `firstPersonNode` is a `org.w3c.dom.Node`, the runtime can not cast it to `javax.swing.text.html.parser.Element`. Any reason why not to use `org.w3c.dom.Element` for `firstPersonElement`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have wrong imports. Make sure imports are correct.

Remove `import javax.swing.text.html.parser.Element`

Make sure imports are:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
```

As an extra check, Make sure node is type Element Node.

```
if (firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) firstPersonNode;
...................
 }
```

Comment: according to NetBeans they are ok and there is no import suggestion as usual when I forget one. I have edited the question with the imports

Comment: These are not compile time issues, these are runtime issues. Netbeans only complains compile time issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot @thinksteep, the problem was with import `import org.w3c.dom.Element;`...solved the problem ;)